# ASP.NET MVC - How to Find the code that returns response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pipeline, trace, nopcommerce

I'm using NopCommerce 3.90, In the products page, calling `/Admin/Product/ProductList` returns this:

**`NotRegistered`** with status of 200 (OK)

and nothing else! I have tried to debug to find the module or piece of code which returns this response but there is really huge amount of codes to review. Plus that, some parallel actions makes it difficult to handle the debug.

I want to find the code which returns this response, how can I do that?

Comment: Check whether there is a route.. then check for an action called ProductList in ProductController of Admin area. If you dont fond it, check your plugins

Comment: Few things are not cleared, 1) Are you trying in default code or any plugin which is overriding functionality of admin product listing page? 2) Did you check log and warnings? 3)If you want to find code you have to show your code or publish it to public repo and give us an URL